# Multiple delegate called for UITextField

Tags: ios, ipad

I have textfield along with other controllers on one of my page, but i notice while testing two delegates as mentioned below get called.. one by one and does not allow me to enter text. if i enter 1st character both delegates gets called simultaneously and keyboard comes down.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

i tried to search for answer but i am not getting why this is happening...

Comment: can you share the implementation code of - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string Method.

Comment: You have any code in `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` .?

Comment: hi, i tried to add my code but i could not edit … but similar code is working with other page…i will try to post..my code

Comment: When you will begin editing in a textfield,textFieldShouldEndEditing will be called for previous textfield. And shouldChangeCharactersInRange will be called for each character entry.

Comment: post your shouldChangeCharactersInRange method here

Answer (score 0):

You might be resigning textfield as first responder in your

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Method. Please check your code and remove

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

from code.